# How to debug Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am running Chrome 67 and I have a website broken -- but working when in anonymous mode. Obviously it's an extension. But which. I have the website whitelisted in ublock origin and yet Console says https://www.example.com/static/js/omniture/s_code_prod.js  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT Of course omniture is ad-like but I even tried to disable uBlock origin and restarting the browser. Still not working. Is there a way to figure out which extension blocks it?

Comment: Use the basic trick: divide and conquer i.e. bisect. Disable half the extensions, see if the problem is fixed. Depending on the result proceed with this half or the remaining one.

Comment: Right... I was more curious about the debugging tools available.

Comment: Try [logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) or `chrome://net-internals`

Comment: A proper debugging method would be nice. Why the browser does not reveal the culprit is beyond me and seems counterintuitive to the debugging process to be forced to guess.